# Optimize range search between two numeric columns having start "From" and "To" end limit

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis

I have a DB Table structure like below with millions of records

| ACCOUNT_RANGE_FROM | ACCOUNT_RANGE_TO | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345670000 | 12345679999 | XYZ |
| 12345680000 | 12345689999 | XYY |

I need to search if a given input number is available in any of the ranges in the table.
As of now we are using the Oracle DB and with query like [number > ACCOUNT_RANGE_FROM and number < ACCOUNT_RANGE_TO ] performance is very slow as it does a Full table search on all the rows.
Creating index on columns is also of little help.

So I was thinking how we can cache such data to improve search time. Application is developed in Spring Boot

Could you please advice if Redis is a suitable candidate for such use case or if any alternate approach needs to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two Sorted Sets one for the beginning of the ranges and one for the end of the ranges. Using the values in your example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD zset:acct_from 12345670000 XYZ 12345680000 XYY
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD zset:acct_to 12345679999 XYZ 12345689999 XYY
(integer) 2
```

Say you are looking for the label for the range where `12345671000` lies:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGESTORE zset:tmp_from zset:acct_from -inf 12345671000 BYSCORE
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGESTORE zset:tmp_to zset:acct_to 12345671000 inf BYSCORE
(integer) 2
```

Inspect the two temp sets:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE zset:tmp_to -inf inf BYSCORE
1) "XYZ"
2) "XYY"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE zset:tmp_from -inf inf BYSCORE
1) "XYZ"
```

The answers is the intersection of the two temp sets:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINTER 2 zset:tmp_from zset:tmp_to
1) "XYZ"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

In Spring:

```
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add("zset:acct_from", "XYZ", 12345680000d);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add("zset:acct_to", "XYZ", 12345679999d);

redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add("zset:acct_from", "XYY", 12345679999d);
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().add("zset:acct_to", "XYY", 12345689999d);

// unfortunately I don't ZRANGESTORE in Spring Data Redis - so you'll have to do the diff in memory - this might be costly (memory-wise)
Set<String> tmpFrom = redisTemplate.opsForZSet().rangeByScore("zset:acct_from", Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 12345671000d);

Set<String> tmpTo = redisTemplate.opsForZSet().rangeByScore("zset:acct_to", 12345671000d, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);

Set<String> result = new HashSet<>(tmpFrom);
result.retainAll(tmpTo);
```

Comment: Thanks for your update , but we have implemented it by referring this article https://groups.google.com/g/redis-db/c/lrYbkbxfQiQ

Comment: If you don't mind accepting the answer, since it's "a solution" that would be great. Thanks.